# AssertEquals returning false for two objects which are same

Tags: java, equals, lombok

I have two user defined objects whose contents are same. But assertsEquals inturn equals method returns false for those objects.

here is the stack trace which contains objects' toString contents as well.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.xyz.test.model.VerificationToken<VerificationToken(id=null, token=, user=User(userId=null, username=null, email=null, password=null, isActive=0, roles=null, imageLocation=null, enabled=false, isAccountNonLocked=true), expiryDate=Sat Dec 22 22:48:49 IST 2018)> but was: com.xyz.test.model.VerificationToken<VerificationToken(id=null, token=, user=User(userId=null, username=null, email=null, password=null, isActive=0, roles=null, imageLocation=null, enabled=false, isAccountNonLocked=true), expiryDate=Sat Dec 22 22:48:49 IST 2018)>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at ....
```

My corresponding class is as follows. This has lombak's @data annotation which generates Equals method.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VerificationToken implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8788934708305097680L;

    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String token;

    private User user; 

    private Date expiryDate;

    public Date calculateExpiryDate(int expiryTimeInMinutes) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, expiryTimeInMinutes);
        return new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }

}
```

My User class is as follows. This also has @Data Annotation which is generates Equals method

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6480423780555564185L;

    @Id
    private Integer userId;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private int isActive;

    private Set<Role> roles;
    private String imageLocation;   
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean isAccountNonLocked;

    public User() {
        super();
        this.enabled=false;
        this.isAccountNonLocked= true;
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.isActive = user.getIsActive();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.imageLocation=user.getImageLocation();
        this.enabled= user.enabled;
        this.isAccountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked;
    }

}
```

My role class is as follows: This also has @Data Annotation which is generates Equals method

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Integer roleId;
    private String role;

}
```

This is my test case which contains one of the objects instantiation.

```
@Test
        public void testCreateVerificationToken() {
            User user = new User();
            String token = new String();
            VerificationToken myToken = new VerificationToken();
            myToken.setToken(token);
            myToken.setUser(user);
            myToken.setExpiryDate(myToken.calculateExpiryDate(24*60));
            ArgumentCaptor<VerificationToken> entityCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(VerificationToken.class);
            when(mocktokenRepository.save(entityCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(myToken);
            verificationTokenServiceImpl.createVerificationToken(user, token);

            assertEquals(entityCaptor.getValue(),myToken);
        }
```

the other object instantiation happens in this code.

```
@Override
        public void createVerificationToken(User user, String token) {
            VerificationToken myToken = new VerificationToken();
            myToken.setToken(token);
            myToken.setUser(user);
            myToken.setExpiryDate(myToken.calculateExpiryDate(24*60));
            tokenRepository.save(myToken);
        }
```

I am not able to understand why two objects are considered as not equal. I would love to give more details if needed. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about overriding the `hashcode()`?

Comment: Where are you using the assert statement?

Comment: what is the result if you call the `equals` method?

Comment: I would start by comparing the sub objects. Identify the smallest scope that behaves unexpectedly, instead of this large nested structure!

Comment: i have not overridden hashcode() anywhere in my code.. i suppose that is taken care by lombak jar via @ Data annotation.

Comment: I have given all the concerned user defined objects.. rest all fields are  java specific classes..

Comment: `lombak`? or `lombok` ?

Comment: result of equals method is false.. thats my worry!!

Comment: Okay.. its lombok.. my bad, it was a typo before

Comment: Where are you invoking the equals method? 
Is it a default implementation or has it been overridden at any point?

Comment: i cant look into equals method because i have used @data annotation which takes care of generating equals method

Comment: please show us instance initialization and comparison.

You can try narrow down number of fields, to find out, what is causing issue.
from first sight lombok code looks OK.

remarks: do not call super() in noargconstructor if class is not in hierarchy + copy constructor does not do the same; you can youse Builder(toBuilder=true) to mimick copy constructor.

Comment: Show the assert code and how you created objects

Comment: I'm afraid equals generated by lombok is not checking for nested object, `User` in your case.

Comment: if dbroundtrip is involved, check the Date instance. It can be changed from java.util.Date to java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: @Deadpool added the instantiation code of objects...

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit are u guessing or are u certain about it? if certain please share your fact in answer with some researched links/articles if applicable

Comment: @MartinMucha No db round trip because its junit.. i am intercepting it before db call happens using mock calls

Comment: @MartinMucha there is no issue in captor stuff.. it works fine in other places as well

Comment: Well if it's not any issue with mocking captor (you're right, captor seems ok in the end), then I don't know. Can you set a breakpoint at assert line, and check objects contents yourself? There has to be something amiss in them. The lombok code seems OK. Based on just reading your code without trying...

Comment: just for fun, try to replace your `Date` field to some `int`, and initialize it with some default value for both cases, let's say 1000. Then, make `Id` as `int` in both classes, not `Long` or `Integer`

Comment: oh, I see the answer, the right answer was with `Date` field how I guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` has millisecond precision, so even if two dates print the same value down to the second, `equals` might return false because they differ by milliseconds.

What you want to do is use a larger granularity than milliseconds. Since your expiry time is in minutes, you can use that as your minimum time unit and set seconds/milliseconds to zero. Here's a quick way to acheive that.

```
public Date calculateExpiryDate(int expiryTimeInMinutes) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, expiryTimeInMinutes);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Well, there's still a chance your test fails once in a while. If the minute changes between your two calls to `calculateExpiryDate` method call :P

Comment: True, but at least that failure will be visible in the output.

Comment: ah! I overlooked that one. Prerequisite to this is actually another issue, irreproducible tests. OP should leave out new Date() in favor some specific time manually set via callendar. This style of writing tests could leave OP wondering why once failed test now works and there is no trace of moments ago preset error.

Comment: @MartinMucha That's what [Stopwatch](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) and `Ticker` are for.

Comment: @maaartinus I don't know guava (shame on me; I should check it) but in pure java since 1.8 one can use Instant and Clock to achiveve (seemingly) the same what classes you recommended does.

Answer (score 4):

The two objects you are comparing have different value in `expiryDate` field. You are generating them using `new Date()` for both the objects at different point in your code using `calculateExpiryDate` method. They won't be equal. Note that precision of date is milliseconds.
I won't suggest you to change `calculateExpiryDate` implementation for a test to pass, instead you can set `expiryDate` to a hardcoded Date value.

Answer (score -2):

`assertEquals` calls the `equals` method of class `VerificationToken`. You don't override this method so `Object`'s default implementation is used that is checking instance equality (`a == b`). If `entityCaptor.getValue()` doesn't return the original instance but e.g. a serialized or cloned copy, that test will fail.

If you expect the same instance to be returned you should use `assertSame` and fix the bug that lead to the return of a different instance. If you expect a different instance being returned, you should first do an `assertNotSame`, implement `equals` and `hashcode` in `VerificationToken` and do the `assertEquals` after `assertNotSame`.

Comment: equals should be generated by @Data lombok annotation

Comment: @MartinMucha "should" is a nice word ;-) and there are different ways that equals-method can be implemented, so it might be worth a look into that method. If e.g. `a.id == b.id`is performed you end up with a result of `false` with the same numbers as value.

Comment: sure, but unless you delombok, you won't look into generated code. And @Data `should` (got it) generate proper hashcode/equals based on all non-transient fields IIRC.

Comment: This is not an answer but is an debugging step to check if there is any issue in lombok @data annotation.. There was no issue with lombok data annotation.

Comment: You can rather trust Lombok generating proper `equals`. There are some border cases, but usually it does what you want (it even compares arrays using `Array.equals`, etc.).